# Print a textEdit in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How can I print the text available in a `textEdit` using Qt creator (C++)? Please help me with this. I created a note pad using a `textEdit`. Now I want to print the note pad content. That mean the text typed in `textEdit`. So please help me.

please mention header files that I need to include as well.

Here is something I tried previous. but it's not working. so please help me with this.

```
void MainWindow::on_action_Print_triggered()
{
    QString textFromField = ui->txtEdit->toPlainText();

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
        printer.setOutputFileName("print.ps");
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(&printer);

                printer.newPage();

        painter.end();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`QTextEdit` already has method which allows you print it's content, so you don't need `QPainter`. Use this (I printed `pdf` as example):

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("outputt.pdf");
ui->textEdit->print(&printer);
```

[print()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextedit.html#print)

And of course you need

```
#include <QPrinter>
```

but I think that it is already added in your project.